# Translucent System Bars on KitKat with Phonegap Build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, android-4.4-kitkat

I'd like to give my Phonegap Build app a modern and fresh look by using the translucent system bars on phones running KitKat but as far as I know it's currently impossible to use custom Android style items. It is possible to select a theme with the `gap:config-file` tag but there isn't a default Android theme with translucent system bars.

Would a proper conclusion be that it's absolutely impossible to use translucent system bars? Or is there some kind of workaround/hack?

If it isn't possible at the moment, could I ever expect this feature in Phonegap Build? Or does the KitKat Webview not allow translucent bars at all?